# Counting JSON data with php

Tags: php, json

I have [this](http://infoabout.me/ISS/facelikes.php) json data, so i having problems to count the numbers of persons appearing in this array, as you can see the format for each element is `{"id":"1038863770","name":"Carol Rodovalho"}`. I tried to change the format to a normal php var using the json decode function and then i used "count" but the result is 1, and that is not true, at least is not counting what i need. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you post this JSON (a scheme) here? See, the link may gone with time, and when it happens, your question will no longer have a meaning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got everything wrapped in a big data object in the json, so do something like this:

```
$data = json_decode($json_data, true);
$data = $data['data'];
echo count($data);
```

PHP Manual for [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).